# How to connect pagination to dataSource between two components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a panel (layout component - parent) which looks like this:
[image]

While it is quite easy to add pagination within the same component, it's not that easy to get it to work in different components. At least to me. I've googled and checked SO but only found either weird answers, which import one component into another, or parent (table) -> child (pagination). I need the exact opposite.
I have already tried to connect Layout(P) with Table(C) through @Input(). Basically, get the `this.paginator` into the Table component, which worked to the point where I wrote `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator`. After that I didn't know what to do or how to get the data back into the Layout component to actually see some change in the pagination.

This might be a bit confusing but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can emit the pagination details to other components using @output and update the records there too. :)

Answer (score 3):

maybe i didn't understand your question  , what i understand its you need to share the same pagination in two components , if that what you need you can try this :

creat Service , for example paginationService :

```
export class PaginationService {
constructor(){}
private _pageNumber: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public pageNumber: Observable<any> = this._pageNumber.asObservable();
public setNewPage(page) {
    this._pageNumber.next(page);
}
}
```

in first component :

```
constructor(private paginationService  : PaginationService ){}

changePagination(page): void {
    this.paginationService .setNewPage(page);
}
```

in seconed component :

```
public currentPage: any = 1;
 constructor(private paginationService  : PaginationService ){}
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.paginationService.pageNumber.subscribe(res => { this.currentPage=res})
 }
```